# Sending a file via email - cannot get attachment to work - Android

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

I've got an app that creates a file in the Download folder

This works fine - it uses this to get the file path:

`File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

Now I'm trying to get that file attached to an email, and I think I'm close, however I get an error from Gmail that it couldn't attach the file.

I changed from `file://` to `content://` because I couldnt get past another error before this.

```
try {
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.email_subject));
    URI = Uri.parse("content://" + exportFilePath);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.email_body));
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.action_export)));
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "failed: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("URI: ", URI.toString());
}
```

The **"exportFilePath"** contains the entire path to the file from when it was created.
it looks like this:
`/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri.parse("content://" + exportFilePath);
```

This is not how you get a `content` `Uri`. [Use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) to serve up the contents of the `Downloads` directory, then use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get a `content` `Uri` for that file. Fairly detailed instructions for using `FileProvider` can be found in [its JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Comment: ok - this makes sense - however how should I make sure the folder is correct when I have to hard-code it into the XML?  I have to put a path into an XML file, however in the Java when I create the file I use the get external storage public directory and pass in the downloads.  Any easier way to do this and keep the file public?

Comment: @EdKuhner: "however how should I make sure the folder is correct when I have to hard-code it into the XML?" -- use `<external-path name="whatever"  />`, where you replace `whatever` with, well, whatever you want. Now your `FileProvider` will be able to serve files from all of external storage. " Any easier way to do this and keep the file public?" -- your real problem is "I've got an app that creates a file in the Download folder". That's going to be increasingly difficult, particularly with Android Q/R. Use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` in your case).

Comment: @EdKuhner: With `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, you *get* a `Uri` that you can use both for saving your content (via `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`) and for your `ACTION_SEND` operation. Plus, the user gets to choose where the file goes, as the user may not want it in the downloads directory.